# how to format date if it is present in "May 20, 2020 16:00:00" into mm/dd/yyyy in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I wanted to format date if it is present in "May 20, 2020 16:00:00" into mm/dd/yyyy in javascript ?

Original Date - May 20, 2020 16:00:00
Formatted Date - 05/20/2020

The original date coming from backend api and the actual format is "May      27, 2020 16:00;00". I don't why there is too much space between month and date. But i am getting the date in this format from api

Comment: If you are lazy, and don’t mind dependencies, moment.js makes this a breeze. Also consider if the output needs to be exactly that format or is “locale dependent”. (See current answer and/or consider larger usage.)

Comment: Actually there a lot of white space b/w May and 20 . it look like "May      20, 2020 16:00:00". It's coming from backed .

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `toLocaleDateString` method on the date object like this

Refer : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString

```js
const date = new Date("May 20, 2020 16:00:00")
const formattedDate = date.toLocaleDateString("en-US")

console.log(formattedDate)
```

Comment: Where “local(e)” can end up as just-about anything.. “..returns a string with _a language sensitive representation_ of the date portion of this date..”

Comment: 1) show a locale being supplied to match the desired output; 2) provide resource that this locale format is well-defined; 3) edit answer to provide any additional clarification(s) about usage to meet the original questions “requirements”.

Answer (score 0):

[Refer to this link for all the available date methods:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

```js
const appDiv = document.getElementById("app");

function formatDate() {
  const d = new Date("May 20, 2020 16:00:00");
  const month = d.getMonth() + 1 + ''
  const formattedDate = `${month.length===1? "0"+month : month}/${d.getDate()}/${d.getFullYear()}`;
  appDiv.innerHTML = formattedDate;
}

formatDate();
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```